# How to get gitVersion to increment version to 1.0.0?

Tags: semantic-versioning, gitversion

I've been trying to use gitVersion to increment a project to version 1.0.0 after some time of incrementing minor and patch versions.

When using `+semver: major` the minor version is incremented. for example, version 0.1.1 got incremented to 0.2.0.

In the official documentation it says the following:

> One thing to be aware of: If the current version is an alpha-version
> (i.e. 0.x.y.), attempting to bump the major version will merely bump
> the minor (eg from 0.2.0 to 0.3.0 instead of 1.0.0). Once the current
> version is greater than 1.0.0, bumping the major version works as
> expected.

I am currently not using a custom configuration file and I was wondering if it is possible to increment the version to 1.0.0 without adding one.

Comment: The short answer is no: that's deliberately how `gitVersion` *works*, and is documented as such. To bypass that, you could avoid using gitVersion at all until you're at version 1.0.0, of course.

Comment: The answer is in the duplicate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74280402/795137

Answer (score 1):

As documented

> If you are using next-version and are experiencing weird versioning behaviour, please remove it, create a git tag with an appropriate version number on an appropriate historical commit and see if that resolves any versioning issues you may have

You can set a new version tag like
**git tag -a v1.0.0 -m "v1.0.0"** on the repository,
gitversion will calculate semVer from the V1.0.0

`git tag -a v1.0.0 -m "v1.0.0"`